Multiple Boxplots within a Time Series
I'm VERY new to creating boxplots (and fairly novice in GGplot2 as well).  I would like to stack boxplots next to each to compare the distribution of ages per year in my dataset.  I have a very much larger data set with around 1000 entries of age per year, but I have created a simple reproducible data set here. My problem is that my code creates one big box plot, I believe of all the ages given that stretches across the x axis of years.  I'm obviously missing something, please help this novice ( I have read and seen many examples, that seem a lot more complicated data than what I am working with, and so, my attempts have not been successful).
Sample data for reproducibility:
df <- data.frame(year = c(2017,2017,2017, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2012,2021,2021, 2023,2023, 2023), age = c(16,17,17, 21,22, 23, 23,24,25, 23,25,24))
My most basic code:
ggplot(data = client_list, mapping = aes(x = year, y = age))+
  geom_boxplot()

another version
ggplot(data = df, mapping = aes(x = year, y = age))+
  geom_boxplot()

I'm sure this is an obvious answer to this but I definitely need help

Try converting year into a factor. i.e. ggplot(data = df, mapping = aes(x = as.factor(year), y = age)) + geom_boxplot()

Thank you! That was it.
